# Is there a standard/well-developed way to serialize Java classes for use in C++ without using a markup format like XML or JSON?

Tags: java, c++, object, serialization

I'm working on a project that will eventually involve Java objects with several billion total fields, and some back-of-the-envelope calculations show that standard serialization techniques will quickly become intractable for inputs of this length (think a 20 gig JSON file). Are there any alternative techniques known?

Comment: You are definitely going to need to stream both the serialization and the transfer. 20 gigs? Yikes.

Comment: Several *billion* fields? Even if all of those are `int`s, we're talking about several gigabytes of data (a billion times 32 bit = 3.7 GiB). You *can* cut down space requirements considerably by throwing out redundancy (which also implies error detection/correction!), endianess-independence, niceness, etc. but it's no magic bullet.

Comment: Lessee ...  You you want a "standardized" way to do a very off-the-wall data interchange between two languages that don't work and play well together??

Comment: I'm just looking for a little guidance guys, snark doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use Sun's XDR format. It's binary, so figure 1/3<sup>rd</sup> the size of text-based formats as a starting point for size. Although they're not (to my knowledge) included in the Java distribution, there are a few libraries to produce/read this format in Java and C++. Since it's used in Sun's ONC RPC, the protocol (and at least some library implementations) have been tested *heavily* over the years. It's also standardized in [RFC 4506](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4506), so you can be about as independent of Oracle as you see fit.

Comment: Interesting... I will definitely look into this. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [protocol buffer](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)
If you have collection of objects and you don't expect a single message (like a big xml) it may work.

Answer (score 1):

You can define some ASN.1 grammar and code/decode your data using common encoding rules i.e. DER, PER, etc.

This flexible notation is used in most common protocols over TCP, such as LDAP. It might be the most efficient way to communicate different platforms, but you have to learn some asn.1 basics and define the grammar. Then implement the marshallers/unmarshallers in Java and also in C++.

[Check ASN.1 in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One)

[Check also Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom implementation of `Serializable` for your Java objects.

Comment: We would go that route, but we need to maintain the architecture of the original Java program as much as possible. It would be optimal to not touch the Java codebase at all.

Comment: @pg1989 -- You know, it would help a little if you'd actually explain your requirements.

Comment: You guys have all the details I do. This is an upcoming piece of a long-term research project, so I don't know every last detail myself.

Comment: @pg1989 -- We have no details.  Is this one process or separate processes?  How is the data to be communicated?  File?  Pipe?  Comm connection?  What sort of data rate are you looking at?

Comment: Hehe, I don't know bud. If I get some news from my co-author in the next few days I'll edit the OP. Thanks for giving my plenty of questions, though!
(That may have come off as sarcastic, but I actually do appreciate your skepticism.)

Answer (score 0):

You might try ASN.1 (yes, I know someone else suggested this here already, but I have some additional information to add).  Since your concern is regarding the size of the data, please note that telephone operators use ASN.1 to handle their CDRs (Call Data Records) in handling the billing of phone calls (whether via land lines, or mobile phones).  They bundle hundreds or thousands of call records into a single message that gets to their billing centers.

My suggestion would be to use PER (Packed Encoding Rules) which was designed originally for the aviation industry due to their need for minimizing bandwidth in Air to Ground communications.  PER was subsequently picked up by the mobile telephony industry where it is currently part of many 3G and 4G protocols.

PER's objective is to avoid sending information over the wire that both communicating parties already know.  So for example, if a field has a fixed length, there is no need to send the length in the message.  If a value has a range, for example, from 5000 to 5007, there are only 8 posible values, so only 3 bits would be used to represent that value.  This is part of why PER achieves such compactness.

Finally, use of a good ASN.1 Tool makes it unnecessary for you to concern yourself about the details mentioned in the previous paragraph.  All you need to do is create the ASN.1 specification describing the information you would like to exchange (which is easy to do - see [ASN.1 Made Simple](http://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/asn1-made-simple/introduction.html)), choose your programming language (C, C++, Java, C# are some of the common ones, but others are also available in some ASN.1 Tools), then use the ASN.1 compiler to generate the serializer/deserializer engine for you.  Note that since ASN.1 itself is independent of the programming language you use, you can easily serialize in C++ and deserialize in Java or vice versa.

You can find a list of ASN.1 Tools (some free, some commercial) at the following URL: http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/asn1/links/index.htm

Comment: Thanks much, I have a lot to think about haha.